# Laravel 8 Duplicate Route Name

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

I don't know what happened with this routing in Laravel 8.

First, I have created a route with `name => 'crm.merchant.klaim.list'` and when I try to redirect to that route name, the response from Laravel is `404`. Then I checked from CLI using `php artisan route:list` and the information about that route name was `crm.merchant.crm.merchant.klaim.list`.

I was trying to use `php artisan route:cache` then `php artisan cache:clear` and the problem didn't resolve.

[image: Screenshot from route:list]

[image: Screenshot from web.php]

```
Route::get('/merchant/klaim', 'Merchant\KlaimController@index')
    ->name('crm.merchant.klaim');
```

when we try command php artisan route:list the return should be down below isn't it?

```
GET|HEAD | crm/merchant/merchant/klaim | crm.merchant.klaim | App\Http\Controllers\Merchant\KlaimController@index
```

but the output is

```
GET|HEAD | crm/merchant/merchant/klaim | crm.merchant.crm.merchant.klaim | App\Http\Controllers\Merchant\KlaimController@index
```

Anyone please help me

Comment: post your code instead of screenshot

Comment: here the code sir,

Route::get('/merchant/klaim', 'Merchant\KlaimController@index')->name('crm.merchant.klaim');

Comment: and return from command route:list is=> GET|HEAD | crm/merchant/merchant/klaim                                  | crm.merchant.crm.merchant.klaim                              | App\Http\Controllers\Merchant\KlaimController@index

Comment: Make sure this round is not defined under a route group where you have ```name('crm.merchant.')``` or any defaul name prefix on RouteServiceProvider. I can't imagine any other reason that can couse this issue. If it isn't the case, share your whole route and RouteServiceProvider file.

Comment: I think you have some route group which id adding prefix.

Comment: Please post your `web.php` file complete image.

Comment: Not the image, but the file or part of the file, because when the image goes down, this question is useless, so please do not share images but literal code

Comment: yeah, the problem have been solved. there is under class who has define as variable. thanks for responses all of u guys. made me a lot, thanks!